# encoding URL into a format readable by google

Tags: python, url, encoding, character-encoding

I would like to know how can I encode a URL so that I can pass it as a parameter into google maps?

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https:%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.889745,1.575165&t=m&z=4

as you can see the URL is being passed as a parameter into the maps.google.com/ url

the question is if i start with a url like http://www.microsoft.com/somemap.kml, how can i encode this URL so that i can pass it into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding):

```
>>> urllib.quote('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/file.kml', '')
'https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml'
```

Comment: @Артём Царионов: the encoding is used as you might guess in URLs (more generally URIs), for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type (HTML forms, e-mails).

Comment: google translates that URL into: https:%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml  whereas python translates into https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml

Comment: both represent the same string if decoded. You could set the 2nd arg to `':'` to produce the exact encoded string.